# How to modify CSS variables in Bulma?

Tags: css, sass, bulma

I am using bulma.css which has CSS variables as seen [here](http://bulma.io/documentation/overview/start/)

```
// Override initial variables here
// You can add new ones or update existing ones:

$blue: #72d0eb // Update blue
$pink: #ffb3b3 // Add pink
$family-serif: "Georgia", serif // Add a serif family

// Override generated variables here
// For example, by default, the $danger color is $red and the font is sans-serif
// You can change these values:

$danger: $orange // Use the existing orange
$family-primary: $family-serif // Use the new serif family
```

These need to be modified with Sass, but I am not using any CSS preprocessor, so how can I modify the variables without altering the main CSS files and doing override?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS doesn't have variables. You cannot edit the variables without using a preprocessor or editing each value one by one (what a variable in SASS would usually do).

Comment: But I am including the css which is bulma.css so, I don't know what is happening

Comment: You would need to use sass and include bulma.sass/bulma.scss and then edit the variables as shown [here](http://bulma.io/documentation/overview/start/)

Comment: But I only need to upload the bulma.css to my server

Comment: You can compile SASS to css. There's no real other way to do it.

Comment: Just to prevent any confusion here. CSS does variables (they're new)... The variables in discussion are SCSS variables. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables